# sql one specific table size and stats

Tags: sql, t-sql, statistics

i have this fine working query for determining 
size,rowcount,ununsed,total mb of db..

it is mssql

thing is is there a way to modify this so it does query only one specific table in DB ? thanks alot. also any hints on how can i query more statistics  ? thanks

```
USE [mydbname] 
GO
SELECT
s.Name AS SchemaName,
t.Name AS TableName,
p.rows AS RowCounts,
CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.used_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Used_MB,
CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) / 128.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Unused_MB,
CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Total_MB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
GROUP BY t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY s.Name, t.Name
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the where condition:

```
WHERE t.Name = 'TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE'
```

And if you have same tables in different schemas

```
WHERE t.Name = 'TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE' and s.Name = 'SCHEMA_NAME_GOES_HERE'
```

Comment: thank you, but i cant really place the where ... would you elp me out ?

Comment: i did put it between inner join and group by, query was executed successfully, but nothing was returned  no results.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you, it is more or less the same query you are using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

okay finally a solution.

```
USE db_name
GO 

SELECT
  t.name                                       AS TableName,
  s.name                                       AS SchemaName,
  p.rows                                       AS RowCounts,
  SUM(a.total_pages) * 8                       AS TotalSpaceKB,
  SUM(a.used_pages) * 8                        AS UsedSpaceKB,
  (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM
  sys.tables t
  INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
  INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    t.name = 'table_name'
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND i.object_id > 255
GROUP BY
  t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY
  t.name;
GO
```